# Adding/Removing url patterns from django during runtime

Tags: python, django, django-urls

For example I have a url in my urls.py-

```
url(r'^my-url/$', views.my_view)
```

Now on a particular action from views, I want to remove this url from urlpatterns and add a new url during runtime. Is it possible, if so, how?

Comment: I've not down-voted your question... Can you tell what is the usecase you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: Down-voter, please explain the reason for down-voting the question?

Comment: @RajaSimon use case - removing a url dynamically, if someone tries to access those urls, they would rather see a 404 not found and adding them back later on with the same procedure

Comment: Have you consider to use authentication based url restriction. Simply check the user if not the user then return 404. That is possible...

Comment: Its not user based, it's more of version based. Depreciating urls when a version is updated, and adding urls for the new version and removing for the previous version

Comment: Okay then why not adding the version url like `/v3/questions` and in the database somehow check this is latest. So any incomming to `/v2/questions` throw 404..

Comment: So there is no way of adding/removing urls on runtime I think?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145855/discussion-between-raja-simon-and-thatbird).

Comment: Use case for this: Sales wants good urls for humans. I have a widget view they want to show foo.com/super-widget-x, they also want a promotions view at foo.com/half-off-widgets.  Sales knows that the shorter the url the easier it's going to be for them to get people to type it into their phone at their convention, but both of these have the same url pattern.  How do we satisfy them?

Comment: I have a use-case. My plugins add urls to the django urlspattern. when a plugin is disabled, the associated urls should be removed from the urlspatterns. when a plugin is enabled urls should be added to the urlspattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing url handler during runtime is not best practice instead you could have the checkpoint in db and handle all the incoming request

models.py

```
class Version(models.Model):
    version_number = models.IntegerField()
    is_latest = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^handler/(?P<version>\d+)/$', views.handler)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def handler(request, version):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Version, version_number=4)
    if obj.is_latest:
        return render(request,'base.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'old.html')
```

Above code authorise only version 4 ( `/handler/4` )